# Windows how to create second instance of Telegram

Tags: windows, windows-11, telegram-messenger

I followed this tutorial to create second instance of Telegram:
Copy paste C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Telegram Desktop into Telegram Desktop 2. Within Desktop 2 create a shortcut of Telegram.exe and name it Telegram 2.

Opening Telegram 2 should open second instance. It does, but the problem is that it is the same as first with user logged in. I need a clean instance so I can login with new user. Any idea how I can remove old login information from new instance?

Comment: That is a telegram issue (not Windows) and you need to ask their support.

Comment: Create an instance in a VM, with another user name?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I removed Telegram and then did the mentioned step on fresh version. Then I can login into each version separately.